# How to insert date using value from previous column

Tags: sql

How to add days using value from the previous column

```
CREATE TABLE rent (
    date of first rent DATE NOT NULL,
    date of 2nd rent   DATE NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO rent VALUES(
  TO_DATE('2011-02-11 16:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
  DATEADD(day,7,'2011-02-11 16:00:00')
);
```

I expect it to write down
date of first rent as `2011-02-11 16:00:00` and 
date of 2nd rent as `2011-02-18`

But that's not selecting the previous column and instead just adding the date to a known value.

Comment: Is there `DATEADD` in Oracle?

Comment: Do you want to add 7 days to '2011-02-11 16:00:00'? If yes why do you expect the result to be: 2011-09-11?

Comment: @forpas mybad edited

Comment: I think it's better to use a trigger for insert and you can update your field using previous data.

Comment: If DATEADD does not cause the INSERT statement to throw an error, then you are **NOT** using Oracle. I will edit your tags to remove `oracle`; please edit again to add your database name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO rent (date1, date2)
    SELECT date1, date1 + interval '7' day
    FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('2011-02-11 16:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as date1
          FROM dual
         ) x;
```

Note that this lists the columns being inserted.  This is a best practice to avoid unnecessary bugs.

The `DATEADD()` function is defined (primarily) in SQL Server.  Oracle uses the more standards-compatible `INTERVAL` arithmetic.

Comment: Or just `date1 + 7`, but I like intervals too.